# What does "Venga nos fuimos de fiesta" mean?

Tags: traducción

He encontrado una [canción interesante](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3We7p78XTo) de Enrique Iglesias. Sin embargo no puedo entender lo que el autor quiere decir en un estribillo:

```
Venga nos fuimos de fiesta de noche y de día
Fusión internacional baila que trae alegría
Venga que siga la fiesta de noche y de día
```

Pienso que sé que significa el último renglón: `Come on, cause the party continues at night and during the day`

Me parece que el principio significa: `Come on, we were at the party night and day`

Pero probablemente no tengo razón.

¡Estaría agradecido por vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part means:

> Yeah, we were at party night and day

just as you said, and the second part means:

> Come on, let's continue the party night and day.

Comment: And what does the second line mean?

Comment: The line is "Fusión internacional / baila que trae alegría", the "international fusion" is probably talking (I'm pretty sure about it) about the fact that the singers are from Puerto Rico and Spain. "Baila que trae alegría" is "Dance  because [dancing] brings happiness", "dance" is in an imperative form.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So "Venga" can be used like "vale", "yeah", in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It might cause confusion, but in the context and the usage, the first phrase doesn't refers to a completed past action, but a continuous one that started in the past and is still occurring: The guy went on party and is still in there. ;)
The last part means something to what @Jaime said: "Come on, let's keep partying all night and day"

He's a party boy. :P